# Want to use Herbert Wilf's snake oil method to show $\sum_k \binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{2n} = \binom{2m+1}{2n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I was trying to use the snake oil method to show that $$\sum_k \binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{2n} = \binom{2m+1}{2n}$$

**tl;dr** I wasn't able to and desperately need help

My approach was to try to establish a more general identity regarding $$\sum_k \binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{s}$$
So I let $$F(x) = \sum_s \sum_k \binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{s} x^s$$
By changing the order of summation, I obtained
$$F(x) = \sum_k \sum_s \binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{s} x^s = \sum_k \binom{2n+1}{2k}(1+x)^{m+k}$$
After this, I noted that $$\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k} = \frac{(1+x)^n + (1-x)^n}{2}$$
Now, $$F(x) = \frac{(1+x)^m}{2}((1+\sqrt{1+x})^{2n+1} + (1-\sqrt{1+x})^{2n+1})$$
I'm having trouble finding the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in this generating function.

**Alternate approach:** I could have created a generating function where the summation was on $m$ but that proved to be fruitless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following request by OP for snake oil method we  evaluate

$$\sum_{0\le 2k\le q+1} {q+1\choose 2k} {m+k\choose q}$$

and introduce

$$F(z, u) = \sum_{q\ge 0} \sum_{m\ge 0}
z^q u^m \sum_{0\le k, 2k\le q+1}
{q+1\choose 2k} {m+k\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} \sum_{m\ge 0}
{m\choose q} z^q u^m 
+ \sum_{q\ge 0} \sum_{m\ge 0}
z^q u^m \sum_{1\le k, 2k\le q+1}
{q+1\choose 2k} {m+k\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 0} u^m (1+z)^m
+ \sum_{m\ge 0} u^m \sum_{k\ge 1}
\sum_{q\ge 2k-1} z^q
{q+1\choose 2k} {m+k\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-u(1+z)}
+ \sum_{m\ge 0} u^m \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q
{q+2k\choose 2k} {m+k\choose q+2k-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-u(1+z)}
+ \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q
{q+2k\choose 2k} \sum_{m\ge 0} u^m {m+k\choose q+2k-1}$$

Continuing with the sum we find

$$\sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q
{q+2k\choose 2k} \sum_{m\ge q+k-1} u^m {m+k\choose q+2k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1} u^{k-1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q u^q 
{q+2k\choose 2k} \sum_{m\ge 0} u^m {m+q+2k-1\choose q+2k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1} u^{k-1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+2k\choose 2k} z^q u^q \frac{1}{(1-u)^{q+2k}}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1} u^{k-1} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{2k}}
\sum_{q\ge 0}  {q+2k\choose 2k} z^q u^q \frac{1}{(1-u)^{q}}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1} u^{k-1} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{2k}}
\frac{1}{(1-uz/(1-u))^{2k+1}}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 1} z^{2k-1} u^{k-1} 
\frac{1-u}{(1-u(1+z))^{2k+1}}
\\ = (1-u) \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k+1} u^{k} 
\frac{1}{(1-u(1+z))^{2k+3}}
\\ = \frac{(1-u)z}{(1-u(1+z))^3} \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k} u^{k} 
\frac{1}{(1-u(1+z))^{2k}}
\\ = \frac{(1-u)z}{(1-u(1+z))^3}
\frac{1}{1-uz^2/(1-u(1+z))^2}
\\ = \frac{(1-u)z}{1-u(1+z)}
\frac{1}{(1-u(1+z))^2-uz^2}$$

Restoring the term in front now yields

$$\frac{1}{1-u(1+z)}
+ \frac{z}{1-u(1+z)}
\frac{1}{1-u(1+z)^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-u(1+z)}
\left(1+ \frac{z}{1-u(1+z)^2}\right)
\\ = \frac{1+z}{1-u(1+z)^2}.$$

Extracting coefficients we get

$$[z^q] [u^m] \frac{1+z}{1-u(1+z)^2}
= [z^q] (1+z) (1+z)^{2m} = [z^q] (1+z)^{2m+1} = {2m+1\choose q}.$$

Now put $q=2n$ to obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{2m+1\choose 2n}.}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here  is different technique based upon generating functions  which might also be convenient.  We use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of  $z^n$  in  a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k}}&\color{blue}{\binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{2n}}\\
> &=\sum_{k}\binom{2n+1}{2k}\binom{m+k}{m+k-2n}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k}\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-2k}\binom{-2n-1}{m+k-2n}(-1)^{m+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}[z^{2n+1-2k}](1+z)^{2n+1}[u^{m+k-2n}](1+u)^{-2n-1}(-1)^{m+k}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^m[z^{2n+1}](1+z)^{2n+1}\sum_{k\geq 0}(-z^2)^k[u^k]u^{2n-m}(1+u)^{-2n-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^m[z^{2n+1}](1+z)^{2n+1}(-z^2)^{2n-m}(1-z^2)^{-2n-1}\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{2m-2n+1}](1-z)^{-2n-1}\tag{6}\\
> &=-\binom{-2n-1}{2m-2n+1}\tag{7}\\
> &=\binom{2m+1}{2m-2n+1}\tag{8}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\binom{2m+1}{2n}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we apply the  *coefficient of* operator twice and we set the upper bound of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we  use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u=-z^2$
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{k\geq0} a_k z^k=\sum_{k\geq 0} z^k  [u^k]A(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we do some simplifications and apply the same rule as we did in (4).
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{2m-2n+1}$.
- In  (8) we apply the  same  rule as we did in (2).